# get link attribute id using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working in wordpress.I want to get data-id value when click on link.

My code is like this:

```
<?php

    $query3 = "select t.* from wp_terms as t 
              join wp_term_taxonomy as tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id
              where tt.parent = ".$res2->term_id;
              $result3 = $wpdb->get_results($query3);


    foreach($result3 as $res3)
    {
?>
        <li>
            <a href="##" class="sub_cat_name" data-id= "<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>"><strong><?php echo $res3->name; ?></strong></a>
        </li>
<?php
     }
?>
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub_cat_name").click(function(){
        var cat_id = $(".sub_cat_name").attr("data-id");
        alert(cat_id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on different link then it alert only fist term_id.So what code should I have to write to get different id while click on different link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get data-id value using 'data' like.

```
$(".sub_cat_name").click(function(){
    var cat_id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(cat_id);
    });
```